# How to print to file after getText()

Tags: java, file, output, awt

I'm learning AWT and made an applet that will save info on a file

```
import practice1.AccountRecord;
public class GUI extends Frame implements ActionListener{

Label account_number = new Label("Account number");
Label first_name = new Label("First name");
Label last_name = new Label("Last name");
Label account_balance = new Label("Balance");

TextField account = new TextField(20);
TextField first = new TextField(20);
TextField last = new TextField(20);
TextField balance = new TextField(20);

Button save = new Button("Save into File...");
Button enter = new Button("Enter");

GUI(){
    this.setTitle("Bank account");
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(account_number);
    this.add(account);
    this.add(first_name);
    this.add(first);
    this.add(last_name);
    this.add(last);
    this.add(account_balance);
    this.add(balance);
    this.add(save);
    this.add(enter);
    save.addActionListener(this);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
        {System.exit(0);}
    });
}

public void actionPerform(ActionEvent evt) throws Exception{
    AccountRecord record = new AccountRecord();
    if(evt.getSource()==save)
    {
        record.accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(account.getText());
        record.firstName = first.getText();
        record.lastName = last.getText();
        record.balance = Integer.parseInt(balance.getText());

        try{
            File f = new File("D:\\AccountRecord");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);

            fw.write(record.accountNumber);
            fw.write(record.firstName);
            fw.write(record.lastName);
            fw.write(record.balance);

            fw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Label err = new Label("Error");
            add(err);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    GUI ct = new GUI();
    ct.resize(300,200);
    ct.show();
}
}
```

Was I wrong with file writing or I didn't getText successfully? I couldn't print anything on the txt file. And will the label come up when file writing fail? I'm quite struggling with Java.

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: @aleb2000 Nothing came up, btw if I'm not wrong then I will have a error label if there are exceptions right?

Comment: Anyways my first suggestion is to debug inside the `actionPerform()` method and see if your program actually go inside the if statement.

Comment: Also since you are using only one action listener I don't think you need to check `if(evt.getSource() == save)`

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Runs fine here. The err label won't be visible this way. First, add a `System.err.println(e);` to the ecxpetion catch block. Probably you can't write to `D:\\AccountRecord` or there is a format error (`parseInt()`).

Comment: Use 'printStackTrace ()' and u will get whats yoru error, and better way is do t use Exception because its general ex. Use 'IOException' & 'FileNotFoundException'

Comment: @aleb2000 I haven't been able to solve it yet

Comment: @PeterMmm  I've changed it to AccountRecord.txt
I changed the catch block it but it didn't print anything.
When I press Save button while debugging, the current debugging line didn't run into actionPerform(). So what is my problem? Where is my mistake setting function to a button?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 faults:

- The method name to override is `actionPerformed`.
- You cannot add `throws Exception`, because the original method do not throw anything.

You should write this method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  // ...
}
```

You have written a method that is never used by the AWT framework.

Comment: I cannot understand how the OP even gets that code to *compile* given the incorrectly spelled method name.. The only thing I can think of is that they are ignoring errors their IDE is reporting, and it allows for running code that does not compile properly. (A good case against using such an IDE - dangerous even in the hands of experts.)